# rebuild previous build for a jenkins job manually

Tags: jenkins

I could click **Build Now** to build a jenkins job again if the job is corresponded to a **specific branch**.
What if the job is related with **multiple branches**? That is, I utilized **wildcard branch specifier**.
When I click **Build Now**, it will rebuild **the last build**. I'm wondering if there is a way to rebuild those **previous builds**.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can rebuild any build with his own parameter.
1. Install rebuild plugin.
2. select the build that you want to rebuild and press rebuild.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzLyf.png)

Comment: Important! rebuild plugin always build your last changes from git